# How to add manually a library to Android in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, svg

Hello I'm new in react native and I was try to add the `[react-native-svg][1]` library

And I think the problem is in the last step, `MainApplication.java`

```js
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();

  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  packages.add(new new SvgPackage());
  return packages;
}
```

Error message

> error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
>     - react-native-svg (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-svg")

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you need to add library manually.Starting 0.60 version auto linking is enabled.You don't need to do any linking by your own.

Comment: @ThakurKarthik with `React Native CLI Quickstart`?

Comment: Yes ! I do not recommend expo as sooner or later we want to eject,The React native cli start does support autolinking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to new packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:

```
packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
```